# JQuery Ajax Tabs + Keeping State

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

i've been stuck on a problem and can't seem to find any help for it.. I've tried my own code, searched for tutorials on the matter but nothing seems to hit the mark..

I am currently using JQuery UI tabs for an application. Each tab click is actually loading its contents using Ajax. I now need to expand the functionality and keep the state between the tabs.

Example:

Click Tab A and fill in form documentation.
Click Tab B to look up some information.
Click Tab A and the information still be present.

Does anyone have some insight in how i could accomplish this?

Comment: Which technology are you using underneath? Just filling in by the user shouldn't be a problem..

Comment: Im using php for the ajax queries. I want to be able to click between the tabs and maintain any updates/changes in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do it if you set the `cache` option on your tabs to `true`, e.g.:

```
$('#tabs_selector_here').tabs({
    cache : true,
    ...
    whatever other options
    ...
});
```

**Edit:** it worked for me.

**Edit 2:** If you're looking for something a little more advanced, you can bind a function to one of the tabs events (try `tabsselect`) that scrapes everything from your form and either sends it to the server with an Ajax call or just saves it to somewhere in the DOM.

Comment: Thank toy, i cant believe i missed that option. I've been looking for ages.

Comment: I use that option so that I don't have to completely rebuild a Google Map (with ~10k markers on it) every time the tab is clicked. Cache option = very handy!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set a hidden field in your page that said to not execute the TAB A ajax query and only read the data already loaded in your form.

Or you can create javascript object where you will save the data loaded.